# How can I use a set list of descriptors as "tags" for different items in Excel?

Tags: microsoft-excel, tags, finance

Apologies if something like this has already been answered - I'm relatively new to Excel and am still trying to figure out how everything works. Right now I have a portfolio of companies owned by a PE firm and I'm trying to find a way to label the industr(y/ies) that each company operates within. I started out with something like
[this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PIeGU.png), using VLOOKUP to match the industry number with the industry so I could add them quickly, however some companies operate within multiple industries which breaks this system.

Is there a better way to quickly tag which industries a company operates within so that I can do stuff like count how many companies operate within certain industries, or return which industries a certain company operates within, relatively quickly?

Answer (score 0):

Organise your data as a list, with two columns: company and sector. If a company operates in (say) two sectors it will appear twice in the list: one row will be contain the Company name and its first sector, another row will contain the (same) Company name and its second sector. You can filter and sort the list to get the answers you seek and use worksheet functions like `=COUNTIF()` to determine how many sectors a company operates in or how many companies operate in a particular sector.

You can add a calculated column to your list to convert a sector number to a more descriptive sector name by using `=VLOOKUP()`  if you want. That will allow you to sort/filter on sector name as well as sector number.